# How to test if a port is open to NebulaGrpah Database

Tags: nebula-graph

I know that ports 9779 and 9669 need to be opened to NebulaGraph Database. How to test that these ports are open and available?

`Port:9779` has been opened for NebulaGraph Database. Is there a configuration sample for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, you could do this in many ways, I'll drop some of them:

Assuming you are on a linux machine, you could check all occupied ports with ss or netstats(depending on whether is modern or old) like:

```bash
$ ss -plunt | grep 9669
tcp     LISTEN   0        4096             0.0.0.0:9669           0.0.0.0:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        4096                [::]:9669              [::]:*
```

And this means 9669 is already occupied in all IPv6 and IPv4 interfaces.

Or, you could try to bind that port to see if it's possible like:

```bash
$ python3 -m http.server 9779
Serving HTTP on :: port 9779 (http://[::]:9779/) ...
```

And if the HTTP server can be listening in this port, it means you are free to use it, it's available!

Answer (score 0):

Or you may use Telnet.
For example:

```
telnet 10.0.0.1 9669
```

Search it for detailed instructions.

Comment: Aha, how could I forget to mention telnet :-D! 